# angular 2 file upload

Tags: angularjs, typescript, file-upload

i am new angular 2 , i am trying to use `ng2-file-uploader` to upload a file, 
but when i try to use [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-file-uploader)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-file-uploader/ng2-file-uploader';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/demo.html',
  directives: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class DemoApp {
  uploadFile: any;
  postId: number;
  options: Object = {
    url: 'http://localhost:10050/upload',
    params: { 'post_id': this.postId }
  };

  handleUpload(data): void {
    if (data && data.response) {
      data = JSON.parse(data.response);
      this.uploadFile = data;
    }
  }
}
```

i get a red line under  directives: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES],

```
npm install ng2-file-uploader
```

so dose any one have an idea how to make the directives in the right way ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change for:

```
providers: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES]
```

Okay